# EditText to String null pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to convert an EditText value to String and later store it in Shared preferences.

### - EDIT

activity_my.xml

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="gotonext"/>
```

function gotonext()

```
public void gotonext(View view) {
    EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    if (phone.getText().toString().length() != 10)
        phone.setError("Enter your mobile number!");
    else {
        SharedPrefs ob = new SharedPrefs();
        ob.storephoneno();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Enter_Subjects.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

SharedPrefs.java

```
public class SharedPrefs extends Activity {

EditText pNo,semDate,def,criticalDef;
public static String folder = "mySharedDetails";
SharedPreferences myDetails;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    pNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    semDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.semdate);
    def = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.defaulter);
    criticalDef = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.critical_defaulter);
    myDetails = getSharedPreferences(folder,0);
 }

public void storephoneno(){

    String p = pNo.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myDetails.edit();
    editor.putString("phoneNo",p);
    editor.commit();
}
```

This is the error I'm getting :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

I've referred various other solutions but in vain. Please reply and solve my doubt soon. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where you called `storephoneno()` ?

Comment: you never called `setContentView`. Without this call you have no widgets to look for

Comment: You missed  `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`

Comment: button onclick calls function gotonext() inside that storephoneno() is called

Comment: show your full class with onCreate and onClick.

Comment: Still your question does not make sense to me.

Comment: i set the layout. there is a button. onclicking it, gotonext() is called. inside that, storephoneno() is called on object of SharedPrefs class. its not working. i cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inflate your layout.

If you are doing it in `Activity`, you need to call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT);
```

before any binding (call it after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`)

If you are doing it in `Fragment`, you need Override method `onCreateView`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, container, false);
   rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
   pNo = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
   //bind rest of your widgets in the same way here
   return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I added setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);  but now there is no error in the logcat but app crashes

Comment: Why your `activity_my` contains only button? You need to set Layout here.

Comment: no no the button is just a part of activity_my . layout is set.